# ¿Se puede utilizar varios "While"?

Tags: while

Se que puede ser una preguntar algo tonta o sencilla e incluso mal dicha (Ya tengo un bloqueo mental y aparte me frustre como para pensar de mas), pero prefiero preguntar a que tener esta duda, Apenas estoy entrando en este tema de la programacion por lo cual no se demasiado, mi duda es ¿Se puede utilizar varios "While"?

Estoy haciendo un programa para calcular el primer semestre de varios grupos con  un X numero de alumnos, ya hice el primer semestre pero nose si tengo que cerrar el primer while para utilizar otro  while para calcular otra cantidad de alumno

Comment: La respuesta corta es **Sí**, pero sin un ejemplo de lo que estás haciendo es difícil decir más, tampoco has etiquetado la pregunta con el lenguaje que usas. Puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. También [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Luego [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/311232/edit) la pregunta agregando cual es el problema específico con el que te encuentras y lo que has probado.

Answer (score 0):

Pon lo que tengas de código aun que esté mal para que podamos entender cuál es tu pregunta. De todas formas lo que he podido entender es que quieres hacer algo así:

```
While(condicional1){
    //Código a ejecutar
    While (condicional2){
        //Código a ejecutar
    }
}
```

Mientras el condicional 2 se cumpla, el while se ejecutará siempre que el condicional 1 también se cumpla.
En otras palabras, si el condicional 1 se cumple, se ejecutará todo lo de dentro. Cuando llegue al segundo while, comprobará si el condicional 2 se cumple. Si se cumple el condicional 2, el segundo while se ejecutará siempre que el primer while(condicional 1) se cumpla. Si el condicional 1 no se cumple, no se ejecutará nada.

Comment: Descuida, resolví ese problema, gracias por tu tiempo